# FileSystemWatcher permission issues?

Tags: c#, service, filesystemwatcher

I have a service written and I am using wixtoolset to package it for distribution to a client. When I try to install I the error shown in the screenshot:

[image]

If I comment out the line

```
Watcher = new MyFileSystemWatcher(PathToFolder);
```

then it will install just fine. Is this a permissions issue, or what could be the cause?

Here is the ServiceBase class

```
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceProcess;


namespace DirectoryMonitoring
{
public partial class DirectoryMonitoringService : ServiceBase
{
    protected FileSystemWatcher Watcher;

    string PathToFolder = @"C:\PDFs\";

    public DirectoryMonitoringService()
    {
        Log.Instance.LogPath = @"C:\ProgramData\DirectoryMonitoring";
        Log.Instance.LogFileName = "DirectoryMonitoring";
        Watcher = new MyFileSystemWatcher(PathToFolder);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
}
}
```

And here is the FileSystemWatcher:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;
using System.Net;

namespace DirectoryMonitoring
{
public class MyFileSystemWatcher : FileSystemWatcher
{

    private const string bucketName = "[bucketnamehidden";
    private static string filePath = "";
    private static readonly Amazon.RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
    private static IAmazonS3 s3Client;

    public  MyFileSystemWatcher()
    {
        Init();
    }

    public MyFileSystemWatcher(String inDirectoryPath):base(inDirectoryPath)
    {
        Init();
    }

    public MyFileSystemWatcher(String inDirectoryPath, string inFilter): base(inDirectoryPath, inFilter)
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion);

        //IncludeSubDirectories = true;
        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Size;
        EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Created += Watcher_Created;
        Changed += Watcher_Changed;
        Deleted += Watcher_Deleted;
        Renamed += Watcher_Renamed;
    }

    private static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            using (client.OpenRead("https://clients3.google.com/generate_204"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Watcher_Created(object source, FileSystemEventArgs inArgs)
    {
        Log.WriteLine("File created or added: " + inArgs.FullPath);
        //TODO upload file to S3
        filePath = inArgs.FullPath;

        //if (CheckForInternetConnection())
            UploadFileAsync().Wait(4000);
        //else if (!CheckForInternetConnection())
            //AddToQueue(inArgs.FullPath);
    }

    public void AddToQueue(string path)
    {

    }

    public void Watcher_Changed(object source, FileSystemEventArgs inArgs)
    {
        Log.WriteLine("File changed: " + inArgs.FullPath);
        //Upload file to S3
    }

    public void Watcher_Deleted(object source, FileSystemEventArgs inArgs)
    {
        Log.WriteLine("File deleted: " + inArgs.FullPath);
    }

    public void Watcher_Renamed(object source, FileSystemEventArgs inArgs)
    {
        Log.WriteLine("File renamed: " + inArgs.FullPath);
    }

    private static async Task UploadFileAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);

            //await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(filePath, bucketName);

            Log.WriteLine("FilePath: " + filePath);

            using (var fileToUpload = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(fileToUpload, bucketName, fileToUpload.Name);
            }

            Log.WriteLine("File uploaded: " + filePath);
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
        {
            Log.WriteLine("Error encountered on server. Message: '"+ e.Message +"' when writing an object");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message: '" + e.Message + "' when writing an object");
        }
    }
}

}
```

Any ideas? It ran just fun if I installed manually with the Developer Console cmds, but no success with wixtoolset.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604' or one of its 
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
at DirectoryMonitoring.MyFileSystemWatcher.Init()
at DirectoryMonitoring.MyFileSystemWatcher..ctor(String 
inDirectoryPath)
at DirectoryMonitoring.DirectoryMonitoringService..ctor()
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604' or one of its dependencies. The 
system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604'
at DirectoryMonitoring.MyFileSystemWatcher.Init()
at DirectoryMonitoring.MyFileSystemWatcher..ctor(String 
inDirectoryPath)
at DirectoryMonitoring.DirectoryMonitoringService..ctor()

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604
(Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Darwin 
Ecosystem/Directory Monitoring/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : DirectoryMonitoring, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files 
(x86)/Darwin Ecosystem/Directory Monitoring/AWSSDK.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files 
(x86)/Darwin Ecosystem/Directory 
Monitoring/AWSSDK.Core/AWSSDK.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files 
(x86)/Darwin Ecosystem/Directory Monitoring/AWSSDK.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files 
(x86)/Darwin Ecosystem/Directory 
Monitoring/AWSSDK.Core/AWSSDK.Core.EXE.
```

Comment: Note that you'll get an exception if you attempt to watch a directory that doesn't exist, so perhaps you should check the directory exists before creating the watcher.

Comment: The directory does exist, so that shouldn't be an issue. I will add a check anyway, since that is good form.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I have added the check, but I still get the issue on attempting to install.

Comment: So it appears that it is a problem with setting the bucket region. If I comment out that then it installs fine. Obviously I need that set for the whole thing to work

Comment: Are you getting the problem when you install, not when you start, right?

Comment: so the problem is nothing to do with FileSystemWatcher. Its to do with TransferUtility and uploading to AWS

Comment: @Jodrell When I install. And yes, it does seem to be an issue with AWS. I've tried changing the version the AWS packages in nuget, as well as changing the version of .net that I am using. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd guess that there is a security restriction (firewall) that, by default, prevents a service connecting to an external host. However, I wouldn't expect that to be problem until you actually start the service.

Comment: Initially, it looks like you are missing some dependency for 'AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604'

Comment: @Jodrell Are there further steps I can take to debug the issue? Right now I am just doing a try catch